# What happens when you do server side redirect in getInitialProps? (NextJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a bit of a tricky question in NextJS:

Lets say we have a component that is wrapped with 3 HOCs, each running his own getInitialProps.

The HOCs run in the following order: HOC1 -> HOC2 -> HOC3.

Inside HOC2, there's a redirect to a different page.

My question is,
What would happen on the redirect? Would HOC3 getInitialProps run? Why? Why not?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried testing this locally? I'd assume you could add console logging into each of the `getInitialProps` methods to see if they're called.

Comment: Hey, I just did, and looks like the getInitialProps is still running on following HOCs after a redirect.

Comment: *getInitialProps has a ctx object, which has res & request object inside when being ran server side. I noticed that even when I terminate the response (using res.end()), the next HOCS in the line keeps running. Any ideas how to handle it?